# ACL to restrict access to storage object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage, bucket

We need to create a BigQuery function.  It is unique because it needs to reference two files within object storage.

I don’t have questions on creating the function, but do have access rights question.
Can we grant access to the archive data Google groups (right now it is failing for those that don’t have access to the bucket and I don’t want to grant to everyone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that, by configuring via [Cloud Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) the permissions of access on your Google Cloud Platform Console. You can set the bucket permissions - more information in the documentation [Setting Bucket Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_bucketpermission).

I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [Overview of Access Control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/), where you have more information on how to achieve it.

Let me know if the information helped you!